# How to insert foreign key in mysql using spring jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, datasource, foreign-key-relationship, spring-jdbc

So at the moment the following code works and inserts in to mysql from my java application:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO location(address1, address2, postcode, town)";
sql+= "VALUES(:address1, :address2, :postcode, :town)";

Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("address1", location.getAddress1());
parameters.put("address2", location.getAddress2());
parameters.put("postcode", location.getPostCode());
parameters.put("town", location.getTown());

this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);
```

However, I'm not sure how to add the "type" column in location table. This column/attribute relates to another table called location_type. so if i was to insert it via mysql code I do

```
INSERT INTO location(address1, address2, postcode, town, type)
VALUES("2","abc street","ab1 1cd", "nice town", (SELECT id FROM location_type WHERE type="main")  )
```

How would I go about doing that from a java application?

Comment: Have you tried taking the extended SQL and using it in a prepared statement? I think you should be able to just replace `"main"` with `:type` like you did for the other parameters.

Comment: oh right... of course. silly me. thank you

Comment: Just throwing this out there, you can be using `SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("string", location.getValue)` instead of `Map ... HashMap` in order to chain your methods -- may make things a bit easier.

Comment: @Prancer I ended up using the following instead `SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(location);
        this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, namedParameters);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do it the same way in a Java application:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO location(address1, address2, postcode, town, type)";
             + " VALUES (:address1, :address2, :postcode, :town,"
                           + " (SELECT id FROM location_type WHERE type='main'))";

Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("address1", address1);
parameters.put("address2", address2);
parameters.put("postcode", postcode);
parameters.put("town", town);

this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);
```

There's no reason the database accepts a SQL query from the command line and rejects it when it comes from a Java application.

If the hard-coded main above is in fact another parameter, you would set it the same way as all the other parameters:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO location(address1, address2, postcode, town, type)";
             + " VALUES (:address1, :address2, :postcode, :town,"
                           + " (SELECT id FROM location_type WHERE type= : type))";

Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("address1", address1);
parameters.put("address2", address2);
parameters.put("postcode", postcode);
parameters.put("town", town);
parameters.put("type", type);

this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);
```

Comment: What about when 'main' is set from the java application? so it would be location.getLocationType() in this case.

Comment: You would do the same as for all the other parameters. Edit coming.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can retrieve fk separately, Try this:
First through one query fetch type from location_type table and then try inserting what you got in your main insert query like this :

```
String sqlForType = "SELECT id FROM location_type WHERE type =?";
String type = null;
 try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlForType);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "main");
            // execute select SQL stetement
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {type= rs.getString("type");}
```

And then follow your working code and add type also to your Insert query and HashMap as well which will come from above query result:

```
// your previous working code
//and add this also in your HashMap
parameters.put("type", type);
```

this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);